# Upgrading Ubuntu 10.10 in-place to 12.04 LTS or 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, 10.10

I know there have been several questions on this, and even those marked as duplicates, however I have tried all the suggestions in those and it doesn't work, and I am not able to comment there, and so, sorry, but I'm starting my own question.

I'm trying to upgrade from a 32-bit Ubuntu 10.10 (no GUI) running the latest 64-bit Linux kernel to a 64-bit 14.04 LTS - or even 12.04 LTS.

I tried the advice in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821), namely, run the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g'
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But at the the end it never finds do-release upgrade:

```
bash: do-release-upgrade: command not found
```

I wonder if anybody might have any suggestions for me. Maybe I can't do an in-place upgrade after all?

Comment: 10.10 is too old `do-release-upgrade`. And it's not only end-of-live since 2012-04-10, but the only upgrade path to 12.04 is via 11.04 and 11.10 which are end-of-live, too. The by far easiest and most likely quickest way is to do a fresh installation of 12.04 or 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I mentioned below if an in-place upgrade was not possible. It seems there is no way of avoiding it though. I'm not confident I will successfully move over everything I need to the new installation, but I will try. I'll open another question if and when I run into problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a LiveCD of the release you want.

If the drive is not already partitioned into 3 partitions, for example, `/`, `/home`, and a `swap`, re-partition your drive to reflect something along those lines.

Move `/home` to the home partition.  If there are any customisations in the root partition, move them to a tmp directory at `/home`.

Install the release of your choice, selecting the option `Something Else`.  You will format your root partition, and leave your home partition as is -unformatted.

This will preserve most of your 'personal data'.  You could also place the output of installed packages `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages` and then `sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Desktop/packages && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade` to put them back after the move.  Or you could hand pick.  It's your choice.

I also have a separate partition for `/opt` just because it saves me time/downloads whenever I switch.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but don't understand the instructions. If an in-place upgrade was not possible I was thinking of (1) create a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS distribution on Linode and then (2) use rsynch to copy over the users, their home directories, one hierarchy containing our data, and some auto-start scripts we have. Then swap the IP addresses. It seems like a lot of work because we have so many instances, and I wasn't confident I would be catching all the data. So I was interested in whether an in-place upgrade was possible. It seems the answer is "no" though, right? Thanks.

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions here. 1) This is one machine 2) You have physical access to this machine.  If the entire filesystem (`/` to `/var`) is on one partition, you can do a sort-of-in-place upgrade without (m)any tears by moving your `/home` (and any other branch) to another partition, temporary or permanent. You can migrate them anywhere you have space that you can keep from being reformatted when you install the new image, ostensibly with ubuquity, on a LiveCD.  You're 'grafting' a new root on your filesystem tree.  Setting aside, 'personal' data to be a less traumatic experience.

Comment: Hi. It's on a Linode. It's a VPS. I don't have physical access to the machine, but I have access via the Linode manager or the shell and can make partitions, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @DougLerner, sorry. I've only done it on a machine I can kick.  The general concept *would* be the same.  The procedure *should* be similar.  After preparation, on a 'normal' box it's 15 minutes offline, and another 5 before the *new* partitions are remounted and you can breath.  But the problem is, as always, in the preparation and the details.  Have you sequestered the right data while you pith and replace the brain?...it's always the details. Good luck.

Comment: I feel like kicking this machine. Anyway, Linode support did advise me to just create a new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS distribution and use rsynch to synchronize my users and their home directory and our data, which is thankfully all in one "sandboxed" hierarchy. Based on other posts at this site I was just hoping there was a simpler, in-place way because we have lots of Linodes. Thanks again.